# R: data.table converts to logical in conditional by group operation (in seemingly random way)

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following problem:

```
test <- data.table(v = ceiling(runif(20, 0, 5)), g = ceiling(runif(20, 0, 2)))
setorder(test, g)

test[, (paste0("n", 1:5)) := lapply(1:5, function(x) sum(v == x)), by = g]

test[, (paste0("foo", 1:3)) := lapply(1:3, function(x){ifelse(get(paste0("n", x + 1)) != 0,
                                                       get(paste0("n", x))/get(paste0("n", x + 1)), NA)}), by = g]

test
```

If you run this code several times, then from time to time one of the "foo" variables is converted to a logical and it makes very little sense.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the use of `NA` by default it is `NA_logical_` and if there is only `NA` based on the condition, then it will be a logical column or else it gets coerced to the column type of other observation.  This can be resolved if we use `NA_real_` constant as mentioned in `?NA`

> NA is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value indicator. NA can be coerced to any other vector type except raw. There are also constants NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_ and NA_character_ of the other atomic vector types which support missing values: all of these are reserved words in the R language.

```
test[, (paste0("foo", 1:3)) := 
   lapply(1:3, function(x){
    ifelse(get(paste0("n", x + 1)) != 0,                                          
       get(paste0("n", x))/get(paste0("n", x + 1)), NA_real_)}), by = g]
```

---

Instead of using `ifelse` and specify the correct `NA` based on the column type, an option is also to use `case_when` (from `dplyr`) or `data.table::fcase` which by default return NA (with the appropriate type of the column)

```
test[, paste0("foo", 1:3) := lapply(1:3, 
  function(x) fcase(.SD[[paste0("n", x + 1)]] !=0, 
   .SD[[paste0("n", x)]]/.SD[[paste0("n", x + 1)]])), by = g]
```

-testing

```
lst1 <- replicate(10, {
  test <- data.table(v = ceiling(runif(20, 0, 5)),
     g = ceiling(runif(20, 0, 2)))
  setorder(test, g)
test[, (paste0("n", 1:5)) := lapply(1:5, function(x) sum(v == x)),
   by = g];test[, paste0("foo", 1:3) := lapply(1:3, 
  function(x) fcase(.SD[[paste0("n", x + 1)]] !=0, 
   .SD[[paste0("n", x)]]/.SD[[paste0("n", x + 1)]])), by = g]
}, simplify = FALSE)
```

-checking the one element with only `NA`

```
> lst1[[9]]
        v     g    n1    n2    n3    n4    n5  foo1  foo2  foo3
    <num> <num> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <num> <num> <num>
 1:     4     1     3     1     0     2     4  3.00    NA     0
 2:     5     1     3     1     0     2     4  3.00    NA     0
 3:     1     1     3     1     0     2     4  3.00    NA     0
 4:     4     1     3     1     0     2     4  3.00    NA     0
 5:     5     1     3     1     0     2     4  3.00    NA     0
 6:     1     1     3     1     0     2     4  3.00    NA     0
 7:     5     1     3     1     0     2     4  3.00    NA     0
 8:     2     1     3     1     0     2     4  3.00    NA     0
 9:     1     1     3     1     0     2     4  3.00    NA     0
10:     5     1     3     1     0     2     4  3.00    NA     0
11:     2     2     1     4     0     1     4  0.25    NA     0
12:     1     2     1     4     0     1     4  0.25    NA     0
13:     2     2     1     4     0     1     4  0.25    NA     0
14:     5     2     1     4     0     1     4  0.25    NA     0
15:     5     2     1     4     0     1     4  0.25    NA     0
16:     2     2     1     4     0     1     4  0.25    NA     0
17:     5     2     1     4     0     1     4  0.25    NA     0
18:     4     2     1     4     0     1     4  0.25    NA     0
19:     2     2     1     4     0     1     4  0.25    NA     0
20:     5     2     1     4     0     1     4  0.25    NA     0
        v     g    n1    n2    n3    n4    n5  foo1  foo2  foo3
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is honestly somewhat baffling to me!

Comment: FYI, there are other forms of `NA`, including `factor()[NA]`, `Sys.time()[NA]`, `as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())[NA]`, and `Sys.Date()[NA]`, there may be more in base R, and none of them are `identical`. Outside of base, there's also `bit64::integer64(1)[NA]`, `lubridate::hms("01:23:45")[NA]`, and almost certainly more, though those may be more difficult to find in "normal coding" without explicit use of specific functions to calculate/generate values.

Comment: The second option you provided is interesting, because I thought of it, but then ruined it by manually setting default to NA, so it didn't work again! Your preference for using .SD[[ ]], is it just stylistic or does it have effiency gains? Thank you!

Comment: @Simon `get` can be buggy when it deals with different environment whereas `.SD` or `.SDcols` are standard ways to subset in data.table

Comment: @Akrun Quick follow-up question: If I wanted to use a string as a column name for subsetting ie data[get(string) > X] is there any other way than using get?

Comment: @Simon you can use `data[eval(as.name(string)) > X]` as well

Comment: @akrun Also from some tries and looking at some other posts, aren't you supposed to not use .SD unless you use all of the data, or you lose efficiency? Related to the follow-up question above and from some tests, I have that ``data[,(paste0(foo, 1:4) := lapply(1:4, \(x) sum(a == TRUE & get(paste0(var, x)) == TRUE)]`` is much faster (20x !!) than ``data[,(paste0(foo, 1:4) := lapply(1:4, \(x) sum(.SD[a == TRUE][[paste0(var, x))]]``

Comment: @Simon  `get` may be faster, but my point was that it could get some unexpected issues depending on the env

Comment: @akrun Ok, thank you very much! I'm doing this thousands of times on huge data, so faster is definitely important in my context! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Simon if you need to do this more faster, you may also check `collapse`

Comment: Thank you! And I'm sorry I know that this is not how StackExchange works, but you wouldn't happen to have idea what's going wrong here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71623668/r-running-the-same-data-table-code-inside-and-outside-a-function-yields-differe ... Thanks!